# SQL - How to select the same column two times with different values?

Tags: sql, ms-access

H ey folks,

I've got the following database table:

[image]

I want to get the product name behind the PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID columns. If there was only one column, instead of two (_A and _B) this would be rather easy, however, I am unsure how to reference to the product name from two the PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID columns.

Here is what my SQL query looks like now:

```
SELECT p.PROD_NAME, pv.PROD_VERS_NAME, cl.COMPA_LVL_NAME
FROM TBL_PROD AS p, TBL_PROD_VERS AS pv, TBL_PROD_VERS_ALLOC AS pva, TBL_COMPA_LVL AS cl, TBL_COMPA AS c
WHERE p.PROD_ID=pva.PROD_ID And pv.PROD_VERS_ID=pva.PROD_VERS_ID And cl.COMPA_LVL_ID=c.COMPA_LVL_ID And pva.PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID=c.PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID_B
And p.PROD_ID=66;
```

Basically what I'd need is something among the lines of

```
SELECT p.PROD_NAME_A, p.PROD_NAME_B, [....]
```

PROD_NAME_A would need to be the name of the ID in PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID_A and PROD_NAME_B the product name of PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID_B.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this? Do I need to do subqueries or something?

best regards,
daZza

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MS Access?

Comment: Access..................

Comment: You had the tag for SQL server, that's why I asked.

Comment: Just realized. Must have clicked on the suggested tags. Fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's ok:

```
    SELECT pa.PROD_NAME, pb.PROD_NAME, pv1.PROD_VERS_NAME, pv2.PROD_VERS_NAME,cl.COMPA_LVL_NAME

    FROM TBL_PROD AS pa, TBL_PROD AS pb,TBL_PROD_VERS AS pv1, TBL_PROD_VERS AS pv2,
TBL_PROD_VERS_ALLOC AS pva, TBL_PROD_VERS_ALLOC AS pvb, 
TBL_COMPA_LVL AS cl, TBL_COMPA AS c

    WHERE 
    pa.PROD_ID=pva.PROD_ID And 
    pv1.PROD_VERS_ID=pva.PROD_VERS_ID And 
    pva.PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID=c.PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID_A And 

    pb.PROD_ID=pvb.PROD_ID And 
    pv2.PROD_VERS_ID=pvb.PROD_VERS_ID And 
    pvb.PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID=c.PROD_VERS_ALLOC_ID_B And 

    cl.COMPA_LVL_ID=c.COMPA_LVL_ID And     
    p.PROD_ID=66;
```